# Can i have a splash screen while loading linux mint

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, splash

My Linux Mint loads with a black screen. Can I replace this with a splash screen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the release notes:

> **Black splash screen**
>
> In Linux Mint the boot splash screen is completely black. This is by design. Once the system is installed the boot sequence is relatively fast. The black loading sequence doesn't look out of place and it looks consistent across all computers, whatever driver you're using.
>
> If you'd rather get a splash screen you can select one by typing the following command and selecting mint-logo:
>
> ```
> sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Linux mint mate v17.1
The star up logo which is located at **lib/plymouth/themes/mint-logo/logo.png**.
Create your own picture and save to Picture folder name xxx.png
 use Terminal command  cd Picture > dir

```
sudo mv xxx.png /lib/plymouth/themes/mint-logo/logo.png
```